# Быть счастливым со стороны - можно?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> — Мне было очень интересно работать над ролью Дейзи в спектакле
> «Великий Гэтсби». Я понимала, что в душе моя героиня глубоко
> несчастный человек, не нашедший себе места в жизни. И мне
> потребовалось много времени, чтобы найти внутреннее состояние и мотивы
> её поведения.
>
> **— Но ведь со стороны она очень счастлива!**

На месте ли своём эта сторона и не требует ли особого пунктуационного подхода?

Comment: Со стороны _кажется (может показаться), что..._ - чего-то не хватает в высказывании.

Comment: Угу. Но не могу ж я стока многа переписывать! Это реплика интервьюера. Меня интересует, возможно ли такое в разговорной речи? Или пошла уже нерусская речь?

Comment: Возможно, многоточие после "стороны"  спасёт эту недосказанную фразу (как и пауза в устном варианте).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Но ведь, со стороны (= если посмотреть со стороны),  она очень счастлива!**

Можно оформить как вводную конструкцию.

Comment: Ага! Принято! )))